# How to interpret and translate this statement from a Wikipedia article on PCA?

Tags: pca

I have to write a Wikipedia article about Principal Component Analysis in my own language and partially I translate it from the English version, but I don't understand a statement from it, more exactly a part from it. So [it goes like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (emphasis added):

> Mathematically, the transformation is defined by a set of $p$-dimensional vectors of weights or loadings $\mathbf{w}_{(k)}= (w_1, \ldots, w_k)_{(k)}$ that map each row vector $\mathbf{x}_{(i)}$ of $\mathbf{X}$ to a new vector of principal component scores $\mathbf{t}_{(i)}= (t_1,\ldots, t_p)_{(i)}$, given by $\mathbf{t}_{k(i)}=\mathbf{x}_{(i)}\cdot\mathbf{w}_{(k)}$ in such a way that the individual variables of $\mathbf{t}$ **considered over the data set** successively inherit the maximum possible variance from $\mathbf{x}$, with each loading vector $\mathbf{w}$ constrained to be a unit vector.

I don't quite understand what "considered over the data set" means. I understand the rest of it, but I'm not a native English speaker and I don't understand this expression.

Comment: I find it confusing as well and I think this paragraph would only improve if these five words were simply deleted. (Not that this paragraph is super-clear apart from that...)

Comment: @amoeba So I should simply ignore those and I can translate it without losing any important information?

Comment: I think so, yes. We say, for example, "variable $t$ has variance $\sigma$. This means that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (t_i-\bar t)^2 = \sigma$. So variance is defined via a sum over the data set. But it is very cumbersome to say "variable $t$ *considered over the data set* has variance $\sigma$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is one heck of a contorted sentence!  The problem is that it tries to present a half dozen ideas all at once.  Let's unpack it into comprehensible pieces, devoting one (much shorter) sentence to each idea.

For context, let's begin with this paragraph, which sets everything up.

> PCA is mathematically defined as an orthogonal linear transformation that transforms the data ...
>
> Consider a data matrix, X, with column-wise zero empirical mean (the sample mean of each column has been shifted to zero), where each of the n rows represents a different repetition of the experiment, and each of the p columns gives a particular kind of datum (say, the results from a particular sensor).

**Translation into English:**

When each repetition of an experiment yields the same number of distinct values $p$ (such as the results from various sensors), the data can be arranged into a matrix $X$.  Its $n$ rows record the experimental results (in any order).  Its $p$ columns correspond to the different values, or *variables.*

Often, before applying PCA, $X$ is modified  by "centering" the variables: the mean of each column is subtracted from each value in that column.

Now for the problematic sentence:

> Mathematically, the transformation is defined by a set of p-dimensional vectors of weights or loadings $\mathbf{w}_{(k)} = (w_1, \dots, w_p)_{(k)}$ that map each row vector $\mathbf{x}_{(i)}$ of X to a new vector of principal component scores $\mathbf{t}_{(i)} = (t_1, \dots, t_p)_{(i)}$, given by    $${t_{k}}_{(i)} = \mathbf{x}_{(i)} \cdot \mathbf{w}_{(k)}$$
> in such a way that the individual variables of t considered over the data set successively inherit the maximum possible variance from x, with each loading vector w constrained to be a unit vector.

**Translation into English:**

PCA converts $X$ into a matrix $T$ of the same dimensions.  It replaces each row of experimental results $\mathbf{x}_{(i)} = (x_1, \ldots, x_p)_{(i)}$ by a row of "principal component scores," which are the values of new variables $\mathbf{t}_{(i)} = (t_1, \dots, t_p)_{(i)}$.  Each score is a linear combination of the entries in its row, written as the dot product with a "loading vector" $\mathbf{w}_{(k)} = (w_1, \dots, w_p)_{(k)}$, $${t_{k}}_{(i)} = \mathbf{x}_{(i)} \cdot \mathbf{w}_{(k)}.$$

$\mathbf{w}_{(1)}$ is chosen to be any unit vector that maximizes the variance of the column of scores $t_{1(i)}$ it produces. (The choice is not unique). $X$ is then modified by subtracting the score-scaled loading vectors $t_{1(i)}\mathbf{w}_{(1)}$ from the rows. This process is repeated until all $p$ of the loading vectors and the $p$ associated scores have been found.

Comment: I am not sure what is your take on what is the supposed meaning *specifically* of the words "considered over the data set", but overall your version is of course much better than the one on Wikipedia, +1.

Comment: Someone should edit the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @whuber Thanks a lot for the answer, it is clearer now. I think this is what Steven Pinker meant in his article about academic writing: http://chronicle.com/article/Why-Academics-Writing-Stinks/148989/

Comment: Good article.  The problem of turgid, murky writing applies widely outside academia, too.  I have spent a great amount of time completely rewriting reports written by engineers or geologists, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

It means that on another data set of the same variables, PCA factors will not work the same way: they won't exactly orthogonal etc.

Comment: Hmmm. I am not sure that *this* is what was really meant here, see my last comment to the OP.

Comment: You might be right, but this is the only way I see this interpreted

Comment: Well, I suggested another interpretation in the comment above, but who knows; I don't find it worthwhile to debate what an unknown Wikipedia editor might have possibly meant. +1 mainly not to leave this question "unanswered".

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. For the time being, I accepted amoeba's suggestion, but I'll come up with an answer too, after my teacher revised it (and if you're interested too). I hope it will be clearer after it. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Narancs: As you mentioned your teacher and said that you "had to" translate this wiki article, I am curious if this is an actual assignment that you got during your studies? If so, interesting.

Comment: @amoeba The assignment is not to translate the wiki article, but to write one in Hungarian that is not already written. If the English (or whatever language you understand) version seems well written, than you can translate parts of it. If something is too complicated or not understandable, than I can obviously alter that sentence, paragraph etc. It's mainly my method of writing this way. I've got a lot of information from other sources, but since this is my first Wikipedia style article I'm a bit confused. But of course, I will refine it from time to time.